# .htaccess - point dir1/dir2/index.php to /dir1/page.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to set my Apache server up so that when someone visits, say, site.com/kittens/ (or site.com/kittnes/index.php), they would actually get to view site.com/certainpage.php. Of course I could copy certainpage.php to /kittens/ and rename it index.php, but it seems like a really lame way to do it.

Any help? I feel like this shouldn't be something too complex.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You have many options. You can use URL Rewrite (see https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ so you know how to do it). You can use a symbolic link. You can use PHP to redirect or just include the other file. I assume you want to do URL Rewrite.

Comment: Hi there - yeah sure. When people visit site.com/kittens/, I want them to actually see site.com/somepage.php.

Comment: Please note that if the URL Rewrite does not work, it may be that the server does not allow it. Then, you can try a symbolic link, which may not be allowed. Then, you can do the in-page redirect using php headers.

Comment: @DwarfVader: Did below answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *rewrite rule* to keep the URL the same but swap the contents out for that of another file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^kittens/(index\.php)?$ /certainpage.php [L]
```